# How to get the information stored in the hls playlist CHARACTERISTICS field from the avplayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I´m trying to guess if a certain subtitle has accessibility options to show that information in the UI layer I´m working on.

I´m using the Apple´s example stream bipbop:

```
https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8
```

That playlist has several subtitles, some of them with accessibility characteristics, for example this one:

```
EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",CHARACTERISTICS="public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound",URI="subtitles/eng/prog_index.m3u8"
```

You can see it has the following characteristics:

```
CHARACTERISTICS="public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound"
```

From the app point of view I´m retrieving all the subtitles with this piece of code:

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup * subtitleSelectionGroup = [asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
for (AVMediaSelectionOption * subtitleOption in subtitleSelectionGroup.options) {
    NSLog(@"%@", subtitleOption);
}
```

An this is the output of the AVMediaSelectionOption created from the subtitle we were talking about:

```
<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x14785320, locale = en, mediaType = 'sbtl', tagged media characteristics = {public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound}, title = English, default = YES>
```

As you can see the AVPlayer is reporting me that information in the field

> tagged media characteristics =
>   {public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog,
>   public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound}

since I can see it in the output of the NSLog

The question is, how do I query those from code? Is there any specific field in the AVMediaSelectionOption class? can´t find one

Thanks!